# Does there exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $A^n=I_2,$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}?$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Here's the matrix

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $I_2$ represents the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

**My trial**

I'm claiming that there do not exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $A^n=I_2.$ Suppose it exists, then

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know that $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
but I don't see a contradiction coming. Any help, please?

Comment: <strike>$\operatorname{det}(A)=0$ while $\operatorname{det}(I_2)=1$.</strike> Following your idea. Your computation implies that if you multiply once again by $A$ you keep getting $A$ as a result. Therefore, $A^n=A$.

Comment: Can you show  $A^n=A $?

Comment: In addition to the first comment, you have already proved that no power will ever be the identity by induction.

Comment: Look for "idempotent matrix". Your matrix is idempotent, so it is never equal to $I$.

Comment: @Thomas Shelby: By induction, right?

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Thomas Shelby: Done that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because your matrix $A$ is singular.

Particularly, if you multiply the matrix with all zeroes in its first row, the resulting matrix has again all zeroes in its first row:

$$A\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
v & w
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
v & w
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
? & ?
\end{bmatrix}$$

so

$$A.A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
? & ?
\end{bmatrix}$$

and, similarly

$$A.A.A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
? & ?
\end{bmatrix}$$

and so on,
and you want to obtain $1$ in the upper left corner.